# How to search for a specific file with batch

Tags: windows, batch

I want to create a batch and need to find a specific file, is it possible to find it?
It has to be a command that searches through all drives until it finds the file, I want it to be usable for everyone.

For example I want to find "FarCry4.exe", I need it to be universal for other people, because maybe some people don't have Far Cry 4 installed at the default directory, like me.

I tried `findstr /x /c:"FarCry4" *.exe` but after completing it just tells me that it can't be opened and then it closes automatically.

Is it possible with the `findstr` command, or does the user has to exchange his path with mine?

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I wanted to add what I've tried in first time, but I forgot...
I am really sorry, I feel so dumb D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible with the findstr command

FindStr "Searches for strings in files" (see `findstr /?`). So your command there is looking for the string "FarCry4" INSIDE all EXEs, it has nothing to do with file names.

> For example I want to find "FarCry4.exe", I need it to be universal for other people, because maybe some people don't have Far Cry 4 installed at the default directory.

You can use `dir` with the `/s` option to search all sub-directories from the current.

Head to the root of the drive (ie `c:\`) and run the following:

`dir FarCry4.exe /s /b 2>null`

You will need to run this for each drive in the system that you want to search.

The `/b` will cause "bare" output, so there will be no headers, and each of the found files will include their full path.

Run `dir /?` for more info on Dir's options, and the `2>null` will cause errors reported by Dir (access denied, path too long, etc.) to be redirected to [Null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) instead of the screen.

Comment: Is it possible to do something with the `if` command? like if it doesn't find that file, to search through drive `b:\ ` , `d:\ `  ... and if the file is found to do something with goto? I don't need the code for it, just want to know if something like this is possible.